# Why does mysql allow me to enter password for non existing mysql user

Tags: mysql, users

My mysql server has 2 users -

```
root
robb
```

But when I try to login with another user it let's me enter password -

```
hussain@magic-laptop:~$ mysql -u jon -p
Enter password:
```

Shouldn't it give an error saying `user: jon donesn't exist`?

Comment: the mysql client gathers the password BEFORE it contacts the server. So the client couldnt know if the username is going to fail before contacting the server. (techinically -p just means ask me for a password, not 'check if I need to enter a password')

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure someone else will be able to provide a more informed answer than this, but a common-sense guess would be that this is a security feature.

If someone is attempting a brute-force attack, they will need the username and password using the system described above. If MySQL reported invalid users before prompting for a password, half of the work is already done for the attacker.

This is purely theoretical, as I haven't tested anything or been informed on the subject by anyone else - just an educated guess based on other systems.